# Finding depth with SIFT or another feature detector

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, feature-detection, stereo-3d

I have a project, that aims for detecting distance to particular object(e.g traffic signs). 
I have calivrated stereo-rig, and first thing I did was to find disparity image and then depth. However, since I need only distance to particular objects in the scene, I thought, that calculating disparity map is pretty long and heavy task, so I switched to feature detection method. 
The idea here is following: I find similar features on both images, and then find disparity(just substract one feature point from another matched) only in the bboxes specified(i have attached the image).

The feature detector works correctly, however when I convert this disparities to actual depth, I have bad results, with a huge error. I convert them with following formula:

```
disparity = feature_matched1.x - feature_matched2.x

depth = baseline * focal / disparity.
```

The caluibration parameters seems to be correct and not the issue.

I want to ask, if I do this thing properly and is is possible to find depth? Maybe I have discoreved some false assumptions and I can not find depth like this method.

[image: Example. Number are distances in mm.]

I can provide code, if it is necessary, however, I think it is more approach-related question.

Comment: Your general approach is fine and also used in practice. Your error might lie in your implementation. Also, why are you only including the x coordinates for disparity calculation? You might get better results by using SSD and L2 norm instead.

Comment: @TA, okay, nice news to hear about approach. Can you please explain, what is SSD? L2 norm is euclidean distance, right? I do not understand though, how I should compute disparity with it, if you can explain that it would be perfect. Because I thought, that we should only consider x values in disparity computation

Comment: If your picture is normalized to have all features in the same plane, you don't need to care about the y-values as they should be the same. I'm not sure if that's the case in your pictures. As for the disparity calculation, you could compare the mean of the squared distances of several close features to be more robust.

Comment: @TA, yes, the pictures are little-bit offset of the one plane. Still don't understand about squared distances... Because as from information I had, the stereo-imaging must compute only horizontal difference